# How to use Integral/Fractional functions with Num

Tags: haskell, types

(I am rather new to Haskell, and to functional programming in general so may be doing things completely wrong)

I am building a puzzle in Haskell, and have been told that forcing the least as possible is the best (type-wise). So instead of making things of an *Integral* type, or a *Fractional* type, I am using a parametrized type:

```
data Orthotope a = Orthotope ...
```

and in almost all functions I use the class constraint

```
(Num a)=> ...
(Num a,Ord a)=> ...
```

however, In some specific functions I need division (and once sqrt).
I am aware I can use **(/)** for Fractional, and **div** for Integral, (fromIntegral where needed) and even that I can use *Data.Typeable* to check which it is, but have been told that that is almost always the completely wrong approach.

Is there a better way to division and sqrt, on a type which isn't completely known? Or is this a case where I should use tests on the type itself?

(I am trying to find a way to be able to do something to Also Fractional's and also Integral', and if it works on more types, even better. (as opposed to using a less general type))

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a single operation which does "nearly exact" division on types that support it and rounding-down-division on types that can only represent whole numbers is a common source of bugs in other languages. I would propose that you keep the distinction that Haskell has, by offering *different* operations on those two classes of types, and force the user to consciously choose between rounding division and more standard division.

Comment: Generally speaking, I completely agree, but is that still true, in a smallish sized project, that nothing else will be using? and in that case, to have the choice done by choosing to use either An Integral type, or a Fractional type? (what the type denotes in the program, is the type if values of the vector space. so using only Integral numbers makes sense, but eventually I might add non-orthotope shapes, and then might want Fractional, and without changing the basic code) thanks

Comment: @ypw I don't see why any part of what I said should be specific to large programs.

Comment: @ypw Every time I think I have written a small enough program that there can be no bugs, I pay for my hubris.

Answer (score 0):

`Floating` would be the most general type which supports both `sqrt` and division.

You can have ghci tell you this by defining a function which uses both and having ghci tell you what its type is:

```
ghci> let f x y = sqrt x / y
ghci> :t f
f :: Floating a => a -> a -> a
```

Also, note that `div` is not exactly the same as `/` since the former rounds the result to always return an integer.